# Jersey REST service as Mule pooled component doesn't work as expected

Tags: java, spring, rest, jersey, mule

I am trying to get a Jersey resource working as a pooled component in Mule ESB 3.4.0.

The Mule flow configuration looks like this (the Jersey resource is managed by Spring):

```
<jersey:resources doc:name="REST">
  <pooled-component>
    <spring-object bean="myRestResource"/>
    <pooling-profile maxActive="3"/>
  </pooled-component>
</jersey:resources>
```

This is defined inside the `<flow/>` tag.

I assumed that this will produce 3 instances of the service which will be reused.

When running 100 calls to the service (each call in its own thread), I see that only one instance of the service (Jersey resource) is called if annotaed with @Singleton, and 100 different instances are called without @Singleton.

How can I ensure that only 3 instances are created and reused?

Comment: try changing the annotation to RequestScope and  initialisationPolicy="INITIALISE_ALL"  in the pooling-profile and check if solves it